# How to create year-over-year plots in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following df

```
player  season pts
  A      2017   6
  A      2018   5
  A      2019   9
  B      2017   2
  B      2018   1
  B      2019   3
  C      2017   10
  C      2018   8
  C      2019   7
```

I would like to make a plot to look at the stability of `pts` year-over-year. That is, I want to see how correlated `pts` are on a year-to year-basis. I have tried various ways to plot this, but can't seem to get it quite right. Here is what I tried initially:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))

for i in df.season:
  sns.scatterplot(df.pts.iloc[i],df.pts.iloc[i]+1)

plt.xlabel('WOPR Year n')

plt.ylabel('WOPR Year n+1')

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

I thought about it some more, and thought something like this may work:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))

seasons = [2017,2018,2019]

for i in seasons:
  sns.scatterplot(df.pts.loc[df.season==i],df.pts.loc[df.season==i+1])

plt.xlabel('WOPR Year n')

plt.ylabel('WOPR Year n+1')
```

This didn't return an error, but just gave me a blank plot. I think I am close here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks! To clarify, I want each player to be plotted twice. Once for x=2017 and y=2018, and another for x=2018 and y=2019 (hence the year n+1). EDIT: a `sns.regplot()` would probably be better here compared to `sns.scatterplot` as I could leverage the trendline to my liking. The below image captures the stability of the desired metric from year to year.

[image]

Comment: Something like `import seaborn as sns; sns.lineplot(data=df, x='seanson', y='pts', hue='player')`?

Comment: No, that is not quite what I am looking for. I will edit the post and add a picture.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do a to do a self-merge:

```
sns.lineplot(data=df.merge(df.assign(season=df.season+1),
                           on=['player','season'],
                           suffixes=['_last','_current']),
             x='pts_last', y='pts_current', hue='player')
```

Output:

[image]

**Note**: If you don't care for players, then you could drop `hue`. Also, use `scatterplot` instead of `lineplot` if it fits you better.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your second idea:

```
for i in seasons[:-1]:
  sns.scatterplot(df.pts.loc[df.season==i].tolist(),df.pts.loc[df.season==(i+1)].tolist())
```

It seems there were two issues: one is that the Seaborn method expect numerical data; converting the series to a list gets rid of the index so that Seaborn handles it properly. The other is that you need to exclude the last element of seasons, since you're plotting `n` against `n+1`.